# Conflict of time in reserving an venue using php and mysql query

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, ajax

What would be the right algorithm for conflict schedule

```
$conflict = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT venue_category 
                                    FROM user_venuereservation 
                                    WHERE start_of_venue < '$start_venue' 
                                    AND end_of_venue < '$end_venue' 
                                    AND end_of_venue < '$start_venue'") 
                or die("error");
```

Issue

> Name: john
>     the venue the he reserve is court
>
> date of venue 01/01/2017
>     start of venue 1:00PM
>     end of venue 3:00PM
>
> then george he reserves venue at court also
>
> date of venue 01/01/2017
>     start of venue 2:00PM
>     end of venue 4:00PM

the result must be alert as conflict

the second problem is

> Name: John choose venue gym
>     date of venue 01/01/2017
>     start of venue 1:00PM
>     end of venue 3:00PM

no need to alert as conflict because different venue

Comment: Ta Riggs, it was hard to read :)

Comment: Surely as a University student you should be working this out for yourself. You would not want your lecturer to see you asking questions on SO to complete your Course Work

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT post code and effort in a [mcve]

Comment: sorry for that.. im new here in stack, thanks for your right suggestion

Comment: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends and ends after Event B starts